# Java String "1603" to float 16.03

Tags: java, string, floating-point

So I have some java Strings of variable length. It can be from 0 to 999999999 but the last two values should always become the decimal part. I want to convert those strings to float values.
The way I was thinking about was:

```
String strNum = "200";
strNum = strNum.substring(0, strNum.length()-2) + "." + strNum.substring(str.length()-2);
Float num = Float.parseFloat(strNum);
```

But this method is quite slow, and I should also add some way to look if the length is bigger than 2, to avoid `string index out of range`.

My question is: is there any way of doing this in a cleaner and faster way? Otherwise I'll do it as I've been thinking.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
float num = Integer.parseInt(strNum) / 100f;
```

The `f` after `100` is important, and unless needed, use `float`, not `Float`.

Comment: thanks! I knew I was doing some unnecessary weird stuff

Comment: btw, I have two values converted using this method. The values are `17.55` and `2.62` but when added it results in `20.169998`, why doesn't it return `20.17`?

Comment: @deuseux12 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems. Problem can be circumvented by specifying format string to force two decimals: `printf("%.2f", num)`

Comment: Didn't know about this, thanks again. How would you do it in java? Since printf() is for C.

Answer (score 0):

String substring function is costly as it creates new Object.So its better to first convert it into number and then divide by 100 to get the desired output.

```
float num = Integer.parseInt(strNum) / 100f;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure your string will always be digits only what about a nice simple

```
float num2 = Float.valueOf(strNum)/100;
```

Hmm, I type too slow! :)